# Facing issue to access salesforce files as community user customer

Tags: soql, community, sharing

I am facing an issue with the community portal user to access salesforce files. I created a library and assigned it to a public group. But when I logged in as experience user, it is not showing that file. But when I am logged in as System admin, I am able to see the file.

I run the query to check the access for the user to a particular file, which is in library.

```soql
SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel 
FROM UserRecordAccess
WHERE UserId = 'userid'
AND RecordId = 'fileid'
```

I am getting value false, false and none for maxaccesslevel.

And when I am trying to click on the link, it is showing **URL No Longer Exists**.

And also, when I query the visibility for the file, it is showing **All Users**.

How to give access to community user to able to see the file?